# Hibernate: what's the difference between @AuditTable and @AuditJoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate question: what's the difference between @AuditTable and @AuditJoinTable and what are the use cases for each of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AuditTable

> Chapter 7. Generated tables and their content
>
> For each audited entity (that is, for each entity containing at least
>   one audited field), an audit table is created. By default, the audit
>   table's name is created by adding a "_AUD" suffix to the original
>   name, but this can be overriden by specifing a different suffix/prefix
>   (see Chapter 3, Configuration) or on a per-entity basis using the
>   @AuditTable annotation.
>
> The audit table has the following fields:
>
> id of the original entity (this can be more then one column, if using
>   an embedded or multiple id)
>
> revision number - an integer
>
> revision type - a small integer
>
> audited fields from the original entity

@AuditJoinTable

> 9.3. @OneToMany+@JoinColumn
>
> When a collection is mapped using these two annotations, Hibernate
>   doesn't generate a join table. Envers, however, has to do this, so
>   that when you read the revisions in which the related entity has
>   changed, you don't get false results.
>
> To be able to name the additional join table, there is a special
>   annotation: @AuditJoinTable, which has similar semantics to JPA's
>   @JoinTable.

Moreover @AuditTable applies on @Target(value=TYPE) while @AuditJoinTable on @Target(value={FIELD,METHOD}).

@AuditJoinTable : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditJoinTable.html

@AuditTable :https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/envers/AuditTable.html#annotation_type_required_element_summary

Comment: Happy to help :)